# How can I test map() response JSON in jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

What is the best way to test map() response JSON in jasmine service.

In this code, I can get all my type alarms from ws. Now I want to test this service. For this I tried some code like below.

```
 public typegetall(): Observable<Alarm[]> {
        ...
    return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.typegetall), {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
        if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
          this.auth.logout();
        } else {
          return res.StatusDescription.map(alarm => {
            return new Alarm(alarm);
          });
        }
      });
  }
```

I tried this unit test:

```
    describe(`Service`, () => {
         beforeEach(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [AlarmsTableComponent],
                imports: [],
                providers: [
                    { provide: AlarmsService]
            }).compileComponents()
                .then(() => {
                    myComponent = TestBed.createComponent(AlarmsTableComponent).componentInstance;
                    myService = TestBed.get(AlarmsService);
                });
        });
               afterEach(inject([HttpTestingController], (backend: HttpTestingController) => {
              backend.verify();
        }));
             it('alarms get all', inject([AlarmsService], (alarmeservice: AlarmsService) => {
            expect(alarmeservice.typegetall());
        }));
});
```

Can you ask me some idea to testing this?

Edit:

```
it('should return reasonable json ssss', inject([AlarmsService, MockBackend], fakeAsync((service: AlarmsService, mockBackend) => {

    const mockResponse = {
        data: [
            { alarmnumber: 0, alarmdesc: 'All cats are lions' },
            { alarmnumber: 1, alarmdesc: 'Video 1' },
            { alarmnumber: 2, alarmdesc: 'Video 2' },
            { alarmnumber: 3, alarmdesc: 'Video 3' },
        ]
    };

    mockBackend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(
            new ResponseOptions({
                body: [
                    { alarmnumber: 0, alarmdesc: 'All cats are lions' },
                    { alarmnumber: 1, alarmdesc: 'Video 1' },
                    { alarmnumber: 2, alarmdesc: 'Video 2' },
                    { alarmnumber: 3, alarmdesc: 'Video 3' },
                ]
            })));
    });

    service.typegetall().subscribe(alarmstype => {
        console.log(alarmstype)
        expect(alarmstype.length).toBe(3);
        expect(alarmstype[0].alarmdesc).toEqual("All cats are lions");
    });

    tick();
})));
```

the result: 
Error: Cannot make XHRs from within a fake async test. Request URL: http://xxxxxx/v1/products

Comment: The StaticInjectorError -> You must provide in configureTestingModule providers, the service that contains the `logout` method (I called `AuthService` because I guess it's his name).

Comment: The syntax of the providers property is not good. 

`providers: [
   AlarmService,
   DateFilterService,
   AuthService
]`

Comment: I change it, like this: `providers: [AlarmsService, DataFilterPipe, AuthService, Http, ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions]` and the result is Error: Can't resolve all parameters for RequestOptions: (?).

Comment: See [MockBackend documentation](https://angular.io/api/http/testing/MockBackend) and check how `RequestOptions` and `MockBackend` are provides

Comment: I solve,correct:  `providers: [AlarmsService, DataFilterPipe, AuthService, ConnectionBackend, HttpModule,
                { provide: Router, useClass: class { navigate = jasmine.createSpy('navigate'); }
            ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two cases to test : when the `statusCode === 1` and when `statusCode !== 1`.

For the first test :
Mock your backend to return a response as an observable of object with a `StatusCode` property, set to 1.

You should create a jasmine spy for the `logout` method from the `auth` object.

Then, subscribe to `typegetall()` method and check in this subscription if `logout` has been called.

For the second test : 
Mock your backend to return a response as an observable object with a `StatusCode` property, set to 2 AND a `StatusDescription` property to an array of `alarm`, not instanciate as Alarm yet.

Then, subscribe to `typegetall()`, with the return data (your array of Alarm). In this subscription, you can test the length and, for each items, if they are an instance of Alarm.

Check the [official testing documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing) to see how to create your mock response.

For the first :

```
it('should call logout when statusCode is equal to 1', () => 
{
     alarmService = TestBed.get(AlarmService);
     authService = TestBed.get(AuthService);
    /* Put your mock response here, an observable of object with StatusCode set to 1 */
    spyOn(authService, 'logout');
    alarmService.typegetall().subscribe(() => {
        expect(authService.logout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
}
```

For the second :

```
it('should return an array Alarm when statusCode is equal to 2', () => 
{
     alarmService = TestBed.get(AlarmService);
     authService = TestBed.get(AuthService);
    /* Put your mock response here, an observable of object with StatusCode set to 2 and StatusDescription set to an array of 3 alarm object*/
    spyOn(authService, 'logout');
    alarmService.typegetall().subscribe((alarms: Alarm[]) => {            
        expect(authService.logout).not.toHaveBeenCalled;
        expect(alarms.length).toBe(3);
        alarms.forEach(alarm => expect(jasmine.any(alarm instanceof Alarm)).toBeTruthy());
        /*
           Other expectations to check object properties values, such as :
           expect(alarms[0].aProperty).toBe(...);
        */
    });
}
```

For testing error, add the rxjs `catchError` operator on your service ([learn more here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html)):

```
public typegetall(): Observable<Alarm[]> {
    ...
return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.typegetall), {
  headers: headers
})
  .map((response: Response) => {
    let res = response.json();
    if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
      this.auth.logout();
    } else {
      return res.StatusDescription.map(alarm => {
        return new Alarm(alarm);
      });
    }
  })
  .catchError(error => of(`An error occured: ${error}`));
}
```

and test it like this :

```
 it('should get an error', () => 
{
     alarmService = TestBed.get(AlarmService);
    /* Create your mock response error here, an observable created with '_throw' and return a value (ex: 'shit, error !') */
    alarmService.typegetall().subscribe(error => expect(error).toBe('shit, error !'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you suggest any example please?

Comment: @Anolua My response has been edited. I let you see how to create a mock response object.

Comment: Now, this looks good thanks, but response is empty. In fact, I have some data in typegetall(). Can display these data in testing?

Comment: That depends on what you need to be displayed. In your service, in `typegetall`, you can put a `console.log(...)`. It will be displayed when the test will be exectuted.

Comment: Please, can you testing again, but now the result to be field, not success?

Comment: Ops sorry, didn't see your message. I don't know if it's possible, I never try. 
You mean that you want a test in error ?

Comment: these tests are successful, now I tried a test filer. Thnx

Comment: If my solution that I gave you previously works, please, can you approve it ? Thx by advance :)

Comment: Yes of course, but if you can, I want also test field, for this service. Thanx

Comment: Ty dude ! What do you mean by "field" ? :)

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to tell you `failure` , not `filed` sorry

Comment: Hello Adrien, can you see my edit post please, I tried this mockBackend and the result is:  Error: Cannot make XHRs from within a fake async test. Request URL: http://xxxxxx/v1/products